# Hive - Concat String with row data

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, concatenation, hiveql

Am trying to concat a string with data row in a table using Hive.

which looks like this in SQL

```
 SELECT 'Select * from ' + [Column] + '; '
                 FROM table_name
                 ORDER BY [table_name]
```

**Result Should be** - SELECT * FROM abc; SELECT * FROM asd; SELECT * FROM xyz ..

Unable to write or find something related to this in Hive command.

Comment: SELECT 'Select * from ' + [Column] + '; ' FROM table_name ORDER BY [Column]

Comment: have you tried executing it in Hive?if so, do you get an error?

Comment: Use the `concat()` function.

Comment: @vkp Cannot recognize '+'

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create a SQL query within a SQL query?

Answer (score 7):

Use concat() function:

```
'SELECT concat('Select * from ', [table_name],  '; ') 
                 FROM your_table
                 ORDER BY [table_name]'
```

if a [table_name] is a column containing table_name

Comment: This format is not working. The problem here is "" Select * from "" is hard coded and [Column] is dynamic. Have to concat a hard coded string and data from a column dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Concate the string data which is in row.
Say ***x***,***y***  to be the column names.

```
insert into orders(1,"a");
insert into orders(2,"b");
```

Here suppose we want to concate **"a"**,**"b"** as one entity.
So we do as follow

```
select concat_ws(',',collect_list(a,b)) from orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat to accomplish your task. But if you directly put ";" inside concat function it may show "can not recognize input error" to avoid this use \ before ;

**below is the tested and working example of the same**

```
select concat("select * from ", col , " \;") from table
```

output :

**select * from A ;**